# Loading an assembly / module into a dynamic assembly

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit, dynamic-assemblies

I have one assembly that's created already, say `Static.dll`, and a dynamic assembly I'm creating at runtime, say `Dynamic`.  `Dynamic` creates some IL code to create a new type from `Static.dll`.  When `Dynamic` is created (it saves successfully), the executable, when ran, errors out because it's unable to load the assembly `Static.dll` type. I believe this is happening since the `Dynamic` exe output can't find this dll (or at least this is my guess).

How can accomplish adding in this `Static.dll` reference so that when someone runs the resulting executable output of `Dynamic` that it can find the referenced types?

I know about `Assembly.Load()`, but this alone doesn't change anything. Or at least, I'm not sure what this gives me since I don't need to use the type at runtime, but rather when running  the `Dynamic` executable.

Lastly, I control the `Static.dll`, so if there is something I can do with the project to fix it, It could be done, however, it does need to remain separate (I don't want to Emit this library for every time I create a dynamic assembly). Basically, I *think* I want to have my dynamic assembly to have a `.assembly extern mscorlib` in it's manifest save `Static` is place of the mscorlib.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ship Static.dll alongside Dynamic.dll ? If you are using Reflection.Emit, the actual *reference* is added automatically. You should be able to confirm this using reflector. Assembly loading will still follow probing rules relative to the exe root.

Comment: Is there a way to load Static.dll types into Dynamic without having to provide the Static.dll (maybe load the types into dynamic via reflection)? I was able confirm that the .assembly extern Static exists though.

Comment: @OmResolve ILMerge maybe? See answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can accomplish adding in this `Static.dll` reference so that when someone runs the resulting executable output of `Dynamic` that it can find the referenced types?

The reference will be added automatically. Note that normal assembly-probing rules apply when your dynamic assembly executes, so in order to find the assembly. You must (one of):

- ship static.dll alongside dynamic.dll
- put static.dll in the GAC (but please: don't do this!)
- run dynamic.dll in a custom AppDomain with a custom probing-path configuration that lets static.dll be found
- handle AppDomain.AssemblyResolve to provide static.dll
- use something like ILMerge to fuse static.dll and dynamic.dll